# PyCharm: Inserting the date and time

Tags: pycharm

Is there a way to insert the current date and time in PyCharm via a button or hot keys instead of having to retype it every time?

Essentially I would love to type `Ctrl + d` (or something) and it would paste the current date and time.

Answer (score 21):

You can set up a custom Live Template for that. As ["Edit Template Variables Dialog" page](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/edit-template-variables-dialog.html) of PyCharm documentation clearly states, for any variable you use in your Live Template you can define an expression, that can make use of PyCharm's several [built-in functions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/live-template-variables.html).

One of these functions is `date()`. Call it without arguments or specify a date format.

So, steps for setting up a Live Template in your case are:

1. Open `Settings -> IDE Settings -> Live Templates`
2. Choose `Python` from list and click `Add` (green plus to the left) or press `Alt+Insert`.
3. Enter an abbreviation to use and template description.
4. In `Template text` area write `$DATE$` (you can use another variable name though).
5. Click `Edit variables`.
6. Choose expression field next to `DATE` (or whatever you used) and put `date()` there. You may specify date format, if neccessary, e. g. `date("dd MMM yyyy")`.
7. Click `OK`.
8. Don't forget to define a context for the Live Template (blue link right under `Template text` area). Choose `Python` at least.
9. Close `Settings` dialog with `OK`.
10. You may now use a Live Template you defined to insert today's date: enter an abbreviation you chose and press Tab (by default).

**EDIT:** applicable in PyCharm 3.4 Professional Edition

**EDIT2:** to insert time use another PyCharm's built-in function -- `time()`

**EDIT3:** It appears to be implemented with [Java's Velocity templating language](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/DateTool.html). So the symbols in the date string are same as those. Something like:

```
Symbol Meaning Presentation Example
------ ------- ------------ -------
G era designator (Text) AD
y year (Number) 1996
M month in year (Text & Number) July & 07
d day in month (Number) 10
h hour in am/pm (1~12) (Number) 12
H hour in day (0~23) (Number) 0
m minute in hour (Number) 30
s second in minute (Number) 55
S millisecond (Number) 978
E day in week (Text) Tuesday
D day in year (Number) 189
F day of week in month (Number) 2 (2nd Wed in July)
w week in year (Number) 27
W week in month (Number) 2
a am/pm marker (Text) PM
k hour in day (1~24) (Number) 24
K hour in am/pm (0~11) (Number) 0
z time zone (Text) Pacific Standard Time
' escape for text (Delimiter)
'' single quote (Literal) '
```